# How to reference a hyperlink in an XML file with elementtree

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to move data from an Excel file that is formatted in XML with elementtree, and some of the cells have a hyperlink associated with them that I would like to move over as well.

The input is like this:

```
<Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
    <Row>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="headerCenterWrap">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[Change Order #]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="headerCenterWrap">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[Summary]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="headerCenterWrap">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[Change Type]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="headerCenterWrap">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[Status]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="headerCenterWrap">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[Sched Start]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="headerCenterWrap">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[Sched End]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="headerCenterWrap">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[Open Date]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="headerCenterWrap">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[Close Date]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="headerCenterWrap">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[Need By]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="headerCenterWrap">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[Category]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="headerCenterWrap">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[Risk]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="headerCenterWrap">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[Assignee]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="headerCenterWrap">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[Requester]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="headerCenterWrap">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[Priority]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="headerCenterWrap">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[Parent]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="headerCenterWrap">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[CAB Approver]]></Data>
      </Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Cell ss:HRef="https://" ss:StyleID="string_url">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[3392348]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="string">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[[] ASSET:]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="string">
        <Data ss:Type="String" />
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="string">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[Assigned]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="string">
        <Data ss:Type="String" />
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="string">
        <Data ss:Type="String" />
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="date">
        <Comment>
          <Data><![CDATA[-05:00]]></Data>
        </Comment>
        <Data ss:Type="DateTime"><![CDATA[2019-04-25T09:31:54]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="string">
        <Data ss:Type="String" />
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="string">
        <Data ss:Type="String" />
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="string">
        <Data ss:Type="String" />
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="string">
        <Data ss:Type="String" />
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="string">
        <Data ss:Type="String" />
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="string">
        <Data ss:Type="String" />
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="string">
        <Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[3]]></Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="string">
        <Data ss:Type="String" />
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="string">
        <Data ss:Type="String" />
      </Cell>
    </Row>
  </Table>
</Workbook>
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to reference the the hyperlink string so that I can apply the hyperlink in the new file.

It looks like it's stored in the style sheet info, is that even something that elementtree can do?

I've tried looking through elementtree's documentation, but I didn't find anything relevant.

```
i = 0
for row in allrows:
    i += 1
    # print(row.tag + ' ', i)

    # Find all cells in this row
    allcells = list(row.iter('{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Cell'))

    # Start cell iteration here
    j = 0
    for cell in allcells:
        j += 1
        data = cell[0]
        # print(cell.tag + ' ', j, data.text)
        xworksheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value = data.text
        xworksheet.cell(row=i, column=j).hyperlink = cell.hyperlink
```

This is the gist of it, but elementree doesn't have a `.hyperlink` attribute so it doesn't work.

Comment: Post the real XML.  IIRC ElementTree has an `attrib` element that is a dictionary of the element attributes, so you'd need something like `cell.attrib['HRef']` to access it.

Comment: How much of the file do you need? There is a lot of private personal information that's in the file that I have to remove before I post it.

Comment: I tried ~cell.attrib['HRef']~ but I get the error `KeyError: 'HRef'`

Comment: After looking up the .attribute element i tried seeing what this spits out 
~for name, value in cell.attrib.items(): 
    print('{0}="{1}"'.format(name, value))~ 

and the string gets formatted in a weird way 
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}HRef="https://" 

just like the row tag as you can see when I try to enumerate all of the rows

Comment: Which version of Excel is this from? In OOXML the links are stored in the associated `.rels` file.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's not generated by excel. I receive them as an xls file, so Excel 2003 I guess. The problem is that I couldn't find any python extensions that could edit it since it seems to actually be formatted as an xml. Xlrd for example would throw up an unsupported file error.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the weird formatting of the xml file I am working from it looks like commentor  Mark Tolonen was right.

{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}HRef="https://"

I just have to do cell.attrib['{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}HRef'] instead of cell.attrib['HRef']